# Questions on ending of Thor: The Dark World

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, thor-marvel, thor-the-dark-world, loki

Sorry, not quite sure how to format spoilers so I tried to keep the title vague.

Here's for the new Thor movie (just watched it last night):

> How did Loki fake dying (and managed to fool Thor, the reinforcements who found his body and possibly Odin since he would have wanted to see the body after it was brought back)?

And follow-up:

> Also, in the end, he's shown to have pretended to be Odin on the throne while talking to Thor about Thor's decision to stay on Earth. Where is Odin and how did Loki manage to do this? Did he do something to Odin?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Loki was the soldier that told Odin about his own death. We saw him shift. It was the same face he had used when he shapeshifted into a guard in front of Thor earlier in the film. Since every other illusion was cancelled when touched, I'd say he was really in Thor's arms, and the illusion was him dying, not the body. He must have done something slightly different afterwards to create a convincing corpse. Perhaps he found another corpse and disguised it? I'm sure there were plenty around.

I'm interested to see what happened to Odin. Loki probably caught him off-guard while in disguise. I think the events of the film, particularly Frigga's death, really took a toll on Odin, so he wasn't really up to his usual game. Loki no doubt took advantage of that.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks! I didn't see the flash of him shifting into the soldier, so I guess it's my bad. Now it's just a question of what happened to Odin :) I read a theory somewhere else that Odin probably went back into Odinsleep since he woke up halfway through it in the first movie to save Thor and Loki (reinforced by his "moment of weakness" when Odin was arguing with Thor in front of the downed ship after the attack).

Comment: @misceleniious You may want to add Kevin Feige's answer about Odin's fate from this interview: http://io9.com/all-your-questions-about-thor-2s-multiple-endings-1462563061

Comment: Then, what happened to the real soldier Odin sent to Dark World?

Comment: @SachinShekhar: I think we can assume that Loki happened to him.

Comment: I am skeptical of the ending of Thor 2, because at the best, it is simply a plot hole; Loki (as Odin) says to Thor "you once told me there would never a wiser king", but when Thor said that, Loki was already gone from Asgard, so how would he know? Further, as Loki has always wanted the throne, I find it incredibly unlikely that he would offer the kingship to Thor so readily, since there's not really any way for him to know that Thor would turn it down ahead of time. Talk about a major gaffe. I hope there is a solid explanation to come, or I will remain severely disappointed in this scene.

Comment: Also, where was the story arc where Lady Sif was jealous of Jane Foster and competing against her for Thor's affection? It seems like they kind of just skipped over that entirely.

Comment: There are like... thousands of fanfiction about how this progressed. I suggest you people check a3o Some of them are quite hilarious.

Comment: @TylerH I never doubted that Loki knew exactly how Thor would react to that offer. As for Odin's fate I saw a speculation that he is at a secret meeting of the Sky Fathers.

Answer (score 13):

The soldier turns up and says to Odin "...we found a body". Then Odin responds "Loki". Two interpretations: 1) Odin thinks it was Loki's body that was found OR 2) Odin recognizes that the soldier was actually Loki disguised as a soldier, and thus voices out his recognition of Loki.

I like to think that Odin did actually recognize Loki from the first instance and knowing that Loki intended to take over the throne, Odin managed to alert Sif and Volstagg to do something about the Aether before Loki gets hold of it himself.

Answer (score 9):

I don’t have anything to add to the first part of misceleniious’s answer, but there are two interviews of note about Odin’s fate.

In [an interview with io9](http://io9.com/all-your-questions-about-thor-2s-multiple-endings-1462563061), Kevin Feige (President of Production at Marvel) said:

> **Is it safe to say that Odin is dead now?**
>
> I would not say that it's safe to say, no. I don't know what Loki did to him.

This seems like a piece of misdirection, although it's a line that Anthony Hopkins (the actor who played Odin) agrees with. In [an interview with The Los Angeles Times](http://herocomplex.latimes.com/movies/thor-the-dark-world-anthony-hopkins-on-marvel-hiddleston-odin/#/0):

> **Odin’s fate is left rather ambiguous at the end of the new film. What’s ahead for the Allfather?**
>
> I’m not sure. He hasn’t physically died on screen, but I played him as a man who’s on his way out. I think they would have to explain in “Thor 3,” if there is one, what happens to Odin. Or maybe it’ll just be a story line, maybe he went to Tahiti or something for a holiday. I don’t know.

This is quite an interesting answer. (Spoilers for “Agents of SHIELD”)

> At the beginning of AoS, Coulson makes many pointed references to his recovery being in Tahiti. He’s also apparently unable to say the word “Tahiti” without adding the phrase “it’s a magical place”, and it’s been heavily implied throughout the show that something else is going on that he doesn't know about.
>
>  It's unlikely that Anthony Hopkins mentioned Tahiti by coincidence. Whether he’s seen AoS or not, I'll guess that Tahiti is significant in the MCU. Perhaps his comments will make more sense once its meaning in AoS has been explained.

Comment: +1 for the AoS link. It does seem like they're using that show to set up a lot of things

Comment: I'll note that knowing what Coulson's "Tahiti" refers to doesn't help one whit in the "what happened to Odin" department. So it may just have been a random reference, after all.

Answer (score 2):

In the scene where Loki is struck by the Kurse, we don't see him activate the void-grenade on the curse. It's not unreasonable to assume that Loki was the one who activated the grenade, whilst the illusion of himself was the one that got stabbed.

Later we see a guard on the dead dark elf world and a flash of green indicating that Loki is using his illusion magic. Clearly we know that Loki survives from this. What isn't clear is what happened to the guard that went searching on that planet, or how he arrived there (Bifrost vs. Short Cut).

The guard returns to Odin, and says they found a dead body, and Odin says 'Loki.' Not a question though, but sudden realisation. I can only speculate if he is recognising the Guard as Loki, or if he is hopeful that it's not Thor they found, who is admittedly his favourite.

What happens between then and the final scene where Loki!Odin is anyone's guess but I'm sure it will be explained in the next set of films. What's possible is that Odin is the Odin-sleep or in the prison, but that's just speculation.

Answer (score 1):

As you see in the other scene, Loki cuts off Thor's Hand, but it is only an illusion, it might be that he uses the same spell when he is Stabbed by Kurse :D

Answer (score 0):

There was a flash of green as we saw the reinforcement so it's possible that Loki was the reinforcement that told Odin about Loki's death.

Answer (score -1):

According to the director, Alan Taylor, [Odin is dead](http://screencrush.com/thor-2-odin/).

> "That was a big twist. It took us a while to realize that we were actually going to kill him. And then it took us a while to realize that we were going to do that at the end."

Answer (score -4):

My opinion: Odin is still alive, and when Loki pretended to be Odin, the real Odin went to the Dark Planet to search for Loki's corpse.