# What is Odin's fate?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, thor-the-dark-world

In the Thor movie series,

> Loki, disguised as an Asgardian soldier, was left alone with Odin, and when "Odin" next appears in the movie, when Thor spoke to him at the end of the movie to report Loki's apparent death, it is revealed that this "Odin" is actually Loki in disguise. It suggests a possibility that Loki may have assassinated or at least held Odin captive and hidden to take his place in secret. The former is very possible, while the latter seems much more difficult to pull off considering Odin's powers and what little Loki seem to have on hand to use against Odin even despite the element of surprise.

So what really happened?

Comment: Out-of-Universe: They got a greenlight for a third movie, named it "Ragnarok" and needed a really good MacGuffin. In-Universe: All in good time

Comment: The accepted answer on that other question does not address it, but [alexwlchan's answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/45075/31178) addresses it.

Answer (score 2):

[He's dead.](http://screencrush.com/thor-2-odin/)

> [Director] Alan Taylor was a little more blunt in his answer, confirming that Odin is definitely dead and that it was a specific decision they made in the process of developing the film:
>
> "That was a big twist. It took us a while to realize that we were actually going to kill him. And then it took us a while to realize that we were going to do that at the end."

Comment: Funny, because in the article [alexwlchan](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/45075/31178) linked to, that was [released on the same day as yours](http://io9.gizmodo.com/all-your-questions-about-thor-2s-multiple-endings-1462563061), says otherwise. That one is from Kevin Feige. Very interesting!

Comment: @CreationEdge in terms of Words of God, Feige is presumably several levels higher than Taylor, too.